# Postman stopped highlighting JSON in Tests and Pre-request Script tabs

Tags: json, postman, postman-pre-request-script, postman-testcase

Postman stopped highlighting JSON in Tests and Pre-request Script tabs. I can't understand why the highlighting stopped working. The only assumption is that it has something to do with the APIs tab.  The script is just completely grayed out like text.

I have tried to find an answer on the internet, however I have not found any similar case. Reinstalling also did not help to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

the same story,
linux, ubuntu,
Postman for Linux
Version
10.17.6
UI version
10.17.6-ui-230904-0927

Desktop platform version
10.17.4

Architecture
x64

OS platform
linux 5.13.0-52-generic

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).